# getting maximum data from two colums in single table(from only one table) MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have two colums(DES1,DES2) in my table MARKS, i want to find MAXIMUM(for each row in both the columns) marks from those two colums and enter the maximum marks to another column (DES), and if the both columns have same data then enter that same data into column (DES) in [MS ACCESS]

table MARKS

### DES1

34

23

30

### DES2

22

40

30

Comment: Why did you mark this question with `jasper-reports` tag?

Comment: also, you should post what you've tried that does not work.  not a do-it-for-me type post.

Comment: I don't think he's got enough rep to comment. @Nitesh, just edit your question with any follow up comments if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
UPDATE Marks
SET Des = (SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES (Des1), (Des2)) AS value(v))
```

This might be cleaner if you had a bunch of columns to compare, otherwise I would go with the CASE statement. This also works well with null values.

Also, this only works >= SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I quickly through together this has not been tested, though:

```
DECLARE @DES     INT
SELECT @DES = (CASE WHEN MAX(DES1) = MAX(DES2) THEN MAX(DES1)
                    WHEN MAX(DES1) > MAX(DES2) THEN MAX(DES1)
                    ELSE MAX(DES2)
               END)
FROM Marks

...use @DES for your insert
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE  Marks
SET     Des = CASE WHEN Des1 > Des2 OR Des2 IS NULL THEN Des1 ELSE Des2 END
```

Comment: If Des2 is null, this will return null as the max

Comment: @adam0101 Good spot, I hadn't considered NULL values. Answer updated.

Comment: I don't think it's quite right yet. If Des1 is null it returns null instead of Des2

Comment: I think you meant to say "OR Des2 IS NULL"